# Долгий ответ от сервера ВК

Tags: php, вконтакте

```
preg_match('/<div class="err">(.*?)<\/div>/', file_get_contents('http://vk.com/wall1_1'), $error);
preg_match('/<div class="text">(.*?)<\/div>/', file_get_contents('http://vk.com/wall1_1'), $text);
```

Слишком всё долго грузится. Нельзя ли как-нибудь оптимизировать и увеличить скорость загрузки?

Comment: а дуров что говорит?)

Comment: @Gorets, заработался и не выходит на связь :(

Comment: А зачем вы два раза обращаетесь к vk? Прочитайте один раз в переменную и делайте с ней что хотите.

Comment: @istem, если запись доступна, то там нет класса err

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Парсить страницы  VK, да ещё через `file_get_contents()` — глубочайший совок.

Гораздо быстрее, без бубна с регулярками, можно получать записи со стены через [API ВКонтакте](http://vk.com/developers.php#devstep2). Метод [`wall.get()`](http://vk.com/developers.php?oid=-1&p=wall.get) вернёт список записей со стены, и инфу о каждой.

Comment: @sergiks, и правда, чего это я не использовал API. А Вам огромное спасибо. Забрал метод wall.getById

Answer (score 2):

Для взаимодействия с другими сайтами нужно использовать curl, `file_get_contents` хоть и работает, но работать с ней в данном контексте не рекомендуется.

Вот например: [Применение cURL и libcurl в php](http://phpclub.ru/detail/article/curl).

Comment: @olegmar, разве curl быстрее скажется на работе, чем file_get_contents?

Comment: я не думаю, что разница будет серьезной. Ну, Вы же спрашиваете про оптимизацию, curl -  это явно лучшее решение. А долго грузится скорее всего потому что в это время высокая нагрузка на сайт.

Comment: file_get_contents также имеет кучу настроек.

http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.file-get-contents.php

Кстати, баги при загрузке возможны и потому, что тентакль определяет ваш запрос, как запрос от робота (так как заголовки отсутствуют)

Comment: @istem, заголовки же курлом устанавливают?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.stream-context-create.php

Answer (score 1):

```
file_get_contents('http://vk.com/wall1_1'), $error);
```

Это даже назвать нельзя по нормльному. Это не вписывается ни в какие рамки ума и логики.

Как написал [@sergiks](/users/7161/sergiks) есть API контакта. Только с его помощью можно получать инфу с данного ресурса, все остальные бредовые идеи про CURL можно забыть, зачем писать бред? Когда можно обратиться к официальному источнику по его API и с ним работать.

Вопросу, однозначно, минус! За идею реализации.